# MySQL - Chave estrangeira em ON DELETE NO ACTION mas executa ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, apache

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema usando `Apache`, `Hibernate e MySQL`. Mas estou com um problema durante a exclusão de entradas pai de uma chave estrangeira. O banco de dados deveria prevenir a exclusão, porém deleta a entrada pai e todas associadas a ela, através da chave estrangeira `(CASCADE)`. Um `SELECT @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` retorna 1 demonstrando que a verificação está ativa no `MySQL`. Suspeito que o `Apache` ou o `Hibernate` esteja desativando a verificação, mas não sei como.

Aqui está parte do meu banco com as duas tabelas em questão:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema dispensario
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema dispensario
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `dispensario` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `dispensario` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dispensario`.`estado`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dispensario`.`estado` (
  `estado_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Código identificador do estado.',
  `estado_nome` VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Nome do estado.',
  `estado_uf` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unidade da federação do estado.',
  `estado_situacao` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Situação do estado (ativo ou inativo)',
  PRIMARY KEY (`estado_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `estado_nome_UNIQUE` (`estado_nome` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `estado_uf_UNIQUE` (`estado_uf` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `dispensario`.`cidade`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dispensario`.`cidade` (
  `cidade_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Código identificador da cidade.',
  `cidade_nome` VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Nome da cidade.',
  `cidade_estado` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Código do estado do qual a cidade pertence.',
  `cidade_situacao` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Situação da cidade (ativa ou inativa).',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cidade_id`),
  INDEX `cidade_estado_idx` (`cidade_estado` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_cidade_estado`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cidade_estado`)
    REFERENCES `dispensario`.`estado` (`estado_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `dispensario`.`estado`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `dispensario`;
INSERT INTO `dispensario`.`estado` (`estado_id`, `estado_nome`, `estado_uf`, `estado_situacao`) VALUES (1, 'Minas Gerais', 'MG', 1);

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `dispensario`.`cidade`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `dispensario`;
INSERT INTO `dispensario`.`cidade` (`cidade_id`, `cidade_nome`, `cidade_estado`, `cidade_situacao`) VALUES (1, 'Belo Horizonte', 1, 1);

COMMIT;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Verificando a classe modelo.Estado encontrei um trecho de código que pode explicar o problema:

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cidadeEstado")
 private Collection<Cidade> cidadeCollection;
```

Após comentar o trecho `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` a exclusão funcionou como esperado.

```
 @OneToMany(/*cascade = CascadeType.ALL,*/ mappedBy = "cidadeEstado")
 private Collection<Cidade> cidadeCollection;
```

Entretanto, essa Classe de Entidade do Banco de Dados é gerada automaticamente pelo IDE Netbeans de acordo com as especificações do banco de dados. Sou um novato no Hibernate e devo estar deixando alguma opção habilitada ou desabilitada durante o processo de geração das classes que acrescente esta configuração. Exceto, caso estas configurações tenham que ser desfeitas manualmente sempre que as classes forem geradas.

Comment: E como está o código que não faz o que você pretende?

Comment: Adicionei o código que faz a inserção e a remoção no banco na questão.

Comment: Fabio, se a pergunta ainda não teve a atenção que precisas tenta modificá-la mais profundamente. Pequenos edits só para chamar a atênção parece nõ ter valido a pena...

Comment: Agradeço pela dica, mas acredito ter chegado a uma solução sobre o problema. Vou resumir a questão adicionar uma resposta para quem tiver dúvida semelhante ou quiser contribuir com outro ponto de vista.

Answer (score 0):

Até onde pude verificar a IDE Netbeans gera as Classe de Entidade do Banco de Dados automaticamente e define a notação "cascade = CascadeType.ALL" para todas as chaves estrangeiras. Desta forma, o Hibernate desconsidera as restrições do banco de dados cascateando mudanças. Alterar esta notação manualmente sempre que fosse necessário refazer as Classes de Entidade seria pouco prático.

Para resolver o problema adotei como boa prática não depender das restrições do banco para identificar mudanças indevidas. Ao invés de tentar capturar exceções sempre que uma alteração indevida fosse feita, passei a verificar cada alteração antes de executa-la.